# Esp 32 keeps disconnecting from com port

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, espressif

I was trying to upload a blinking coding that was in Arduino IDE but the Arduino IDE can not detect my Esp32 but when i press "EN" i manage to get connection but when i letgo the esp32 disconnect again

Comment: What is wired to your ESP32?

Comment: Nothing is wired to my esp32

Comment: What ESP32 board are you using?

Comment: Esp 32 DOIT DEVKIT V1 board

Comment: I would suggest that you have a dodgy USB cable or socket on that board. Pressing the EN can not do anything to USB, since it has no connection to USB. But it is right by the USB socket, so you may be pressing down on that at the same time, or otherwise moving the connector.

Comment: I have use multiple  cable still the same result

Comment: And if you hold the board completely still with one hand and press EN with the tip of something like a pen does it still exhibit the same symptoms?

Comment: By doing that the Arduino IDE detect my board on com port 3 but when i letgo of "EN" button it disconnect